# Changing the width of input box in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, sass

I have set the appropriate width for my input and it renders fine on all browsers except for IE. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. I even tried this but did not work.

```
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
 width: 50px;
```

}

Comment: You should also provide the related html code or any other code which is related to the issue. It can help us have a better understanding of the issue. We can't help without [a minimal, reproducible sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I've been stuck with IE and min-width since IE completely ignores the min-width. Here is what i've done :

```
    #element {
    min-width: 70px; 
    width: 70px;
    }
    
html>body #element { 
    height: auto;
    }
```

Hope it's usefull